# Best Practice with ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion

Tags: ios, uikit, abaddressbook

Is it acceptable to call the method `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`even when the application may already have been grated access by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` if a call to `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus` returns `kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`.

Comment: Why? In that case the call to `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus` will return a specific value. There will be no need to call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` in that case.